# What is the R programming equivalent of corr_matrix[TARGET_L].sort_values(ascending=False) in Python?

Tags: python, r, correlation

I want to check the correlation of my input variables to my target variable.
What is the R programming equivalent of corr_matrix[TARGET_L].sort_values(ascending=False) in Python?

I already tried Hmisc package and correlation_table(df, TARGET_L) which gives error "Error in correlation_table(df, TARGET_F) :
could not find function "correlation_table"".

Comment: 1. `cor()` from the `stats` package may be all you need to create corr_matrix, but we'd need to see what Python function is making that object. 2. `Hmisc` doesn't have a function named `correlation_table`. The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) includes a reference manual with a list of all functions. 3. You can sort by a column in R using `order()`.

Comment: I read that the Hmisc package includes the funModeling package which has the correlation_table function. But it gives the error I indicated above and if I try to install the funModeling package, it gives the error funModeling package doesn't exist.

Comment: yes, the cor() function provides a nice correlation matrix of all variables. But I also need to exclude nulls, non-numeric columns, and the Target column to use the cor() function.

Comment: I tried the following:
`corr_to_TARGET_BAD_FLAG <- cor((df[colnames(df) != "TARGET_BAD_FLAG"].sapply(df,is.numeric),  use = "complete.obs"), df$TARGET_BAD_FLAG)`

but I get the Error: 
unexpected symbol in "corr_to_TARGET_BAD_FLAG <- cor((df[colnames(df) != "TARGET_BAD_FLAG"].sapply"

Answer (score 0):

Without `df[colnames(df) != "TARGET_BAD_FLAG"]` I was able to get the following to work:
`corr_to_TARGET_BAD_FLAG <- cor(df[sapply(df,is.numeric)], df$TARGET_BAD_FLAG, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")`